# WP8, C#: How do I check the install date of the application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Right now I am creating an app, that has to keep track of how many days since the application was installed. I have searched the entire internet for answers with no luck.

I would like to know how to check the install date of the application.

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: Usually, this is done by lookup in registry entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IsolatedStorageSettings to store the date on first run.

Comment: He has installed the application, but haven't used for many days. Then how can you find the installed date. In this scenario you cannot find the exact installation date & Time.

Comment: It's impossible since you never implemented this in the app. you will need to make a new app. if you implement installation date it will use the update date